# Plotting logistic regression in R with the Smarket dataset

Tags: r, model, visualization, regression, logistic-regression

I'm attempting to plot a simple logistic regression in R for the Smarket data set (in the library "MASS"). I've successfully completed the glm.fit process to calculate the deviance residuals and coefficients, but I'd really like to visualize the logistic regression, but cannot find a simple way to do this.

For more context, I'm using "An Introduction to Statistical Learning". This is an extension of the exercise from page 156-160 (btw, this is not a school requirement, just me trying to figure it out). I imagine this is a relatively easy problem, but I'm new to R and can't seem to get it.

Thanks.

The code I've used is provided below:

```
glm.fit=glm(Direction~Lag1+Lag2+Lag3+Lag4+Lag5+Volume , data = Smarket, family=binomial)
summary(glm.fit)
coef(glm.fit)
```

is there a way to create a visualization of the logistic regression?
I have not included the code to include the library, if this is needed, let me know, and I will add it.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more detail on **how** you would like to visualize this. The geometry is in **R^7** giving you a lot of options.

Comment: FYI, the `Smarket` data set is in the `ISLR` package, not `MASS`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways to visualize the results of a logistic regression, the first, third, and fourth of which are all adapted from the [code](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/software/) for Chapter 5 of Gelman & Hill, *Data Analysis Using Regression & Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*. The code below uses some functions from the `arm` package (which goes with the book):

```
library(arm)
```

1) Plot probability of Direction="Up" over the range of Lag 1 values and for 3 different values of Volume (with other Lag values set to zero, though you can set them to other values if you wish))

```
# Function to jitter class category values
jitter.binary <- function(a, jitt=.05){
  ifelse (a-1==0, runif(length(a), 0, jitt), runif(length(a), 1-jitt, 1))
}

# Sequence of Lag1 values for plotting
x = seq(-5,5.7,length.out=100)

# Plot jittered Direction vs. Lag 1. This shows the actual distribution of the data.
with(Smarket, plot(Lag1, jitter.binary(as.numeric(Direction)), pch=16,cex=0.7,
                   ylab="Pr(Up)", xlab="Lag 1"))

# Add model prediction curves. These show the probability of Direction="Up" vs. Lag 1 
# for three different fixed values of Volume.
curve(expr=invlogit(cbind(1, x,0,0,0,0,1.48) %*% coef(glm.fit)), 
      from=-5, to=5.7, lwd=.5, add=TRUE)
curve(expr=invlogit(cbind(1, x, 0,0,0,0, 0.36) %*% coef(glm.fit)), 
      from=-5, to=5.7, lwd=.5, add=TRUE, col="red", lty=2)
curve(expr=invlogit(cbind(1, x, 0,0,0,0, 3.15) %*% coef(glm.fit)), 
      from=-5, to=5.7, lwd=.5, add=TRUE, col="blue", lty=2)
```

[image]

2) Plot Lag 1 vs. Volume, color the points by the value of Direction, and add the decision boundary. For conceptual simplicity, I've done a new regression with just the two predictors for this, because the decision boundary is a five-dimensional hyperplane for your actual regression. (For models with many predictors, you can still graph the decision boundary in two dimensions by taking 2D slices through the multidimensional predictor space.)

```
# New regression model
glm.fit2 = glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Volume , data = Smarket, family=binomial)

# Probability of Direction="Up" for this model
Smarket$Pred2 = predict(glm.fit2, type="response")

# Set Prediction to "Up" for probability > 0.5; "Down" otherwise.
Smarket$PredCat2 = cut(Smarket$Pred2, c(0,0.5,1), include.lowest=TRUE, labels=c("Down","Up"))

# Graph Lag1 vs. Volume with coloring and point-style based on value
# of Direction
with(Smarket, plot(Lag1, Volume, pch=ifelse(Direction=="Down", 3, 1), 
                   col=ifelse(Direction=="Down", "red", "blue"), cex=0.6))

# Add the decision boundary
curve(expr= -(cbind(1, x) %*% coef(glm.fit2)[1:2])/coef(glm.fit2)[3],
      from=-5,to=5.7, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

3) Plot of average of binned residuals vs. predicted probability of "Up":

```
x = predict(glm.fit, type="response")
y = resid(glm.fit)
binnedplot(x,y, xlab="Pr(Up)")
```

4) Plot the coefficient values with confidence intervals. This isn't specific to classification; just a quick way to visualize the model coefficients.

```
coefplot(glm.fit)
```